# Installing the latest DNVM

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core, dnvm

I currently have DNVM v1.0.0-beta4-10356 installed but there is no `dnvm update-self` command available in this version.

**How do I install the latest available DNVM?**

I have tried this command as the [ASP.NET 5 GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet/home):

```
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
```

It performs the following:

```
Using temporary directory: C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp\dnvminstall
Downloading DNVM.ps1 to C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp\dnvminstall\dnvm.ps1
Downloading DNVM.cmd to C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp\dnvminstall\dnvm.cmd
Installing DNVM
Installing .NET Version Manager to C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin
Installing 'dnvm.ps1' to 'C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin' ...
  Skipping: file already exists
Installing 'dnvm.cmd' to 'C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin' ...
  Skipping: file already exists
Adding C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin to Process PATH
Adding C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin to User PATH
Adding C:\Users\Dave\.dnx to Process DNX_HOME
Adding C:\Users\Dave\.dnx to User DNX_HOME
```

But upon running `dnvm help`, I see that I remain on the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted the entire `.dnx` folder from `C:\Users\{{user}}` and reran the installation command.  It obviously wasn't able to "overwrite".

Answer (score 0):

beta6 just came out and there are [tooling updates that will install the new version of dnvm](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all)

using that will be the easiest solution I think

Comment: the page says "this download is no longer available"

Comment: DNVM no longer exists, that was preview technology during the beta period. now we have the dotnet CLI (command line interface)